# Is there a limit on how many entries the 'Control R' bash shortcut searches?

Tags: bash, shortcuts

I have increased my bash history limit to 10000 and I see that my bash history has grown to approximately 6000 entries. However when I try to search my history using 'Ctrl R', it searches only a portion of the bash history - more specifically just the recent commands.

Is there a configurable parameter using which I can tell bash to search my entire .bash_history file?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Bash history facilities](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-History-Facilities).

[image: histsize]