# Why Bash does not scan all of its own history file

Tags: command-line, bash, command-history

I use a common history for all sessions. It happens to me frequently, that a part of the history is lost, however. Therefore, I just swap different "common session" scripts in a hope that one will fix it, no way so far. It works *mostly*, but not always.

I just decided to look more closely into this, when Ctrl+R `valgrind` showed nothing. Yes, it is in the history file - opening `.bash_history` in an editor and searching shows multiple commands that begin with `valgrind`.
Still, `history |grep valgrind` shows just itself, and in fact, that very command is put into the said `.bash_history`, at the very end of it, long after the other commands containing `valgrind`. And it is not a typo - the history file contains many `iptables` commands, these are invisible by `history` and by Ctrl+R. The more recent history in the same file is visible and accessing it works fine.

I would doubt, that Bash history is broken so much. Any explanation?

EDIT: There is a similar question, with no real answer: [Is there a limit on how many entries the 'Control R' bash shortcut searches?](https://superuser.com/questions/505901/is-there-a-limit-on-how-many-entries-the-control-r-bash-shortcut-searches?rq=1)

Comment: Does this help? https://superuser.com/questions/211966/how-do-i-keep-my-bash-history-across-sessions/578080

Comment: No. As I said, I already use a common Bash history.

Comment: So you did, sorry.

Comment: Can you check your `~/.bashrc` to see what is `HISTSIZE` and `HISTFILESIZE` set to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bash` does not load the whole `~/.bash_history` at the start of the session.
It only loads a number of commands specified by shell variable `HISTSIZE`.

There is a difference between the history that is kept in memory and history that is saved in `~/.bash_history` file. To make `bash` load more from `~/.bash_history` you need to set `HISTSIZE` to a higher number.

[GNU bash documentation](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-History-Facilities):

```
The value of the HISTSIZE shell variable is used as the number of commands 
to save in a history list.
```

The "history list" in the documentation refers to the history kept in memory.

Comment: The commands which can not be recalled are already saved in the history file.

Comment: The size of the history loaded in memory and size of the history that is kept in the HISTFILE are two different things. If your HISTFILESIZE is larger than HISTSIZE then the number of commands loaded into memory can be smaller than the total number commands in your HISTFILE.

Comment: This SO question explains that in detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19454837/bash-histsize-vs-histfilesize

Comment: I extended the answer to explain the difference between the history file and the history in memory.

Comment: My .bashrc contains `HISTFILESIZE=$HISTSIZE`, at least now... I do not know if it was the case when I wrote this question. I will set both to 10M and see if relatively  recent commands are still lost sometimes.